# RavenDB Revision management on application level

Tags: ravendb, data-modeling

Unfortunately this is a very general question...

Imagine an authoring application to create e.g. electric schematics. Engineers draw schematics until they are satisfied with their product and it's ready for production.

At this point a "Revision" would be initiated (say Revision "#1") . From now on all data/documents of this revision can't be changed anymore. It's read-only.

As time goes by, the engineers have smart ideas and start to update the existing schematics based on Revision #1. They add new features, remove features, replace some components with newer versions etc. until they have a Revision #2.

A common requirement this then: What has changed between Rev.1 and 2? Some delta reports are needed.

What would/could that mean with RavenDB?

1. If the engineers start a new revision, would that mean to
   copy all documents and insert them with a new Id like 
   "/proj-1/rev-2/component-1000"? How would I update my relations between documents 
   then? Adjust all relations "manually"?
2. Snapshot the DB? Can I compare a snapshot DB with the current DB?
3. How would I find all the delta between those revisions?
4. If I do not copy all documents or snapshot them, would I need to book-keep all changes in separate documents (event-log style) i.e. DocX has been deleted, DocY has been updated with Value1, DocZ has been added etc?
5. I know that RavenDb has its own revision system. It's based on single changes of a document. Could this be used for advantage here?

Any hints how to model such a system would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RavenDB has the notion of revisions for documents, which create read only snapshot of the document. They are created whenever you modify the document.

For your needs, I would recommend creating: `plans/1238-A` as the document itself.
Whenever you need to stamp a read-only revision, use: `plans/1238-A/revisions/1` or something like that.

I would recommend not modifying any references, point to the same location, but when reading the revision, ask the referenced *revision*.

Comment: Not quite sure if I understood what you are suggesting. 1. Turn on built-in revisions. 2. If a revision on application level is needed and a doc gets updated, store the document with a new ID (in other words: copy it). Added docs get new Id, too. How to handle deleted in Rev.2 ?

Comment: If the Revisions feature is enabled, then when you Delete a document that has revisions, you still have access to its revisions through the 'Revisions Bin'. See https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/server/extensions/revisions.

Comment: I guess I should store it with new Id and immediately delete it. Otherwise I can't distinguish between a deletion while Rev1 was developed and a deletion in Rev2. Another question is how to query all this? I would receive docs with "old" Ids and docs with new Ids. How to take only those which belong to Rev2 (latest modification date)?  Querying on Id (or parts of the Id)is not possible, right?

Comment: To load Multiple Entities that contain a Common Prefix, use the LoadStartingWith method. See [loading-entities - loadstartingwith](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/client-api/session/loading-entities#loadstartingwith)

Comment: @Danielle Didn't know about this! Awesome!